# Ubuntu 20.04 Screen Flickering on DELL G5 5590

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I am experiencing screen flickering (graphics glitches) every few seconds, after a clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on a new DELL G5 5590. Besides the screen glitching, there seems to be no other problem. Some details regarding the problem:

- The laptop came with Windows 10  OS pre-installed, but I chose to remove it during the Ubuntu installation.
- I did not see any flickering issues during a session with the previous OS, Windows 10.
- The second monitor which I have connected on the laptop does not have flickering problems. It is only the laptop monitor that flickers.
- I chose installation of third party drivers during the Ubuntu installation
- Given the default settings in Displays, the laptop monitor is at 144Hz refresh rate and the second monitor at 60Hz
- After installation, I installed the suggested nvidia drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. The output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` was

  ```
  == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
  modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F11sv00001028sd000008EAbc03sc00i00
  vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
  model    : TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile]
  driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
  driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
  driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
  **driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free recommended**
  driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
  driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
  ```

Update: Today I experienced a different problem, the screen glitching got worse. After a few minutes the graphics glitched for good and manual restart was required  (happened 2 times randomly).  I am thinking about re-installing Ubuntu but this time without checking the "third-party drivers software" option, but I am not sure if this a good idea  e.g. missing important drivers, or even related to the problem.

What approach do you recommend to solve this problem? Let me know if I should post additional information. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to Software & Updates → *Additional Drivers* and select one of the offered drivers (see screenshot).

[image: Additional Drivers]

Comment: Great, this seems to have solved the problem. However, I also had to reinstall Ubuntu, without checking the "third party" option this time.  Thanks!